# How to add Timestamp and Interval to generate a column's value in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am getting a 'generation expression is not immutable' error when creating the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE public.instance_lock
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    instance_id character(8) NOT NULL,
    locked_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    locked_for interval NOT NULL,
    locked_until timestamp with time zone NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (locked_at + locked_for) STORED,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

What would be the right way of calculating the value for the column 'locked_until'?

Comment: Why do you need the generated column? You can always read the value like so `SELECT locked_at + locked_for AS locked_until FROM public.instance_lock`. Not having the generated column reduced your table size and thus the volume of I/O on reads and writes.

Comment: The reason why it's failing is the fact that you use `timestamp with time zone` - the actual value depends on the time zone of the client's session and thus may vary and thus the generated value can't be evaluated, because it might be different for different sessions.

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)